# Remove RectTransform from GameObject via Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a GameObject with a RectTransform that I would like to remove via script.
In other words, I want to replace the RectTransform with a regular Transform in the inspector using a script.

In the inspector, you can simply click the RectTransform dropdown and select Remove Component from there and the RectTransform is replaced with Transform. Of course this only works if there are no Components that rely on the RectTransform directly.

[image]

[image]

If I try this approach with a script like: `Destroy(GetComponent<RectTransform>())` I get an error stating:

> Can't destroy RectTransform component of
> 'MyGameObject'. If you want to destroy the game
> object, please call 'Destroy' on the game object instead. Destroying
> the RectTransform component is not allowed.

Of course, this is somewhat expected, since you can't remove a transform from a gameObject. In the case where I am trying to get back the old Transform component however, this behavior is *undesirable*.

So my question is: **is there a way to replace the current RectTransform with a simple Transform component via script, and how is this done?**

Comment: I don't know of a way short of creating a new GameObject, and then transferring over components, values, and references via script.  Out of curiosity, why are you trying to revert a gameObject from a GUI object back to a 3D one?  I'm interested in how that's being used :)

Comment: @AlexM. I'm making an asset that can be used with a SpriteRenderer and Image for both UI and non-UI purposes, I have a component with a button that toggles between Image and SpriteRenderer. Basically when I toggle to Image and then back to SpriteRenderer, the RectTransform remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't delete a conversion.Alternatively, create an empty object and move the entire hierarchy located on that object there. You can simply change the parent of the first child and align the local position, or implement a more complex system, depending on what you need it for.

Comment: I was hoping there'd be a simpler solution. What do you mean with: "You can't delete a conversion"?

Comment: Sorry, English is not my native language and I did not correctly translate the word transform.  Why don't you try storing 2 variants of the object? for Image and SpriteRenderer, or describe what exactly should be happening,why do you need to change the image<->SpriteRenderer in runtime?

Comment: It's not necessarily at runtime, it's done with a button in a custom inspector. I'm doing this, because I feel it's more convenient for the user to click the toggle button, than to make a whole new gameobject. Plus there are quite a few settings involved with my script, which of course can be copied over, but again, it's more convenient just to click a button to toggle.